# How to show two views on one page in drupal

Tags: drupal, singlepage, multiview

How can I show multi views on single page in Drupal?
I need to show two results, (maybe you can think 2 tables, but actually 2 views) on one page.
Anyone please help me.

Comment: Please add details about what you have already tried and how that did not work.

Comment: Actually, I'm implementing ecommerce, using rooms module(it doesn't matter actually).
Currently there are 2 pages, but I wanna show those results on one page.
In other words, I wanna show two results (views) on one page.
Please help me.

Comment: Create "block" displays for the views, then put both blocks in the content area for that page. Or add a footer to the first view, and include the second view that way. 2nd way is probably better

Comment: Can you explain it more detail? I'm novice about "Block".
And currently the result is shown separately, I just wanna show them on one page.
It is now implemented as a view for each result.
Can you tell me how to do it with "Block"?

Comment: Use the 2nd method - add a footer to the first view, when it asks you what you want to put in the footer, choose a view, then choose the 2nd view

Comment: Your method seems good, but i can't find the view i want to add in the choose a view window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the panels module. That will allow you to put views in different types of layout on a page. And take arguments as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a page with your first view. For the second view you have to create a block and add it to that page.

btw: please use https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ for drupal specific questions...

Comment: I can't find any appropriate help there.'

Answer (score 0):

As laebs suggested one way is to create block view and to add it to some region when your page is displayed.

Other way would be embedding the view from template file:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7

With this function you can specify which view and which display you want to embed. You can also pass the parameters this way.

And notice that you have "embed" display type (it may be hidden by default - check view options). If you use it you'll also get those nice "edit view" links when embedding view this way.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways that I know of without using other modules:

1. Use the Views Header/Footer area to load another view. Just click "Add" in the Head/Footer area of the Views UI and you should see "Global: View area".
2. Create a page template and insert the views that you'd like to have on the page within the template using some Drupal API php:

   ```
   <?php
       $view = views_get_view('view_machine_name');
       print $view->execute_display('default', $args);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Actually 2 views are in DB.
You mean I need to make a page in code for wrapping those 2 views?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to make a page template. If you wanted to use the Views block, you could do that. Views headers accept other views to be inserted. I'd do it that way depending on how you want them arranged on the page.

Comment: But the problem is that I can't find those views when I add view block in the footer or header.

Comment: And I tested your php code, I think it gets view, but it doesn't show the whole view.

Comment: What part of the view is it not showing? You'll likely need to remove the $args unless you've set some arguments.